# Failure to compile Audacity on Mac due to "Unknown type LVAL" in libnyquist

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, audacity

Sorry to post it here, because I've got no answers on the Audacity forum.

I'm compiling Audacity on Mac according to the official WIKI step-by-step instructions.

After fixing a lot of dependency issue, I'm now stuck at building the Audacity `Release` target in Xcode8.1.

The Nyquist dependency contains an "undefined" type `LVAL`, with the actual error:

```
Unknown type name 'LVAL'
```

I searched for the keyword in the entire Audacity repo and couldn't find its definition (typedef or #define), nor did I find it in its OS dependency: MacOSX 10.6 SDK bundle.

Where did it come from?

Btw, even after excluding libnyquist dependency from the Xcode build, some source files are still required for compiling the Audacity app target, so there seems no way to bypass this part of the code.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.
Looks like the current-date Audacity Xcode project has bugs. After adding all headers from the `libnyquist` child project as a `Header` Build Phase. The build error disappeared.

So this LVAL is most likely defined in those headers' own dependencies.